# SQL Server, LINQ, C# store data chain information

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I want to store information about compatible products. I have two tables, one for the products, with product_id, and one for its connections.

Table structure like this:

```
+---------+------------+
| Product | Compatible |
+---------+------------+
| id      |  id        |
| name    |  prod1_id  |
| price   |  prod2_id  |
+---------+------------+
```

So, when product 1 is compatible with product 3, I insert to the compatible table id: 1 & 3. When product 1 is compatible with product 5, I insert id: 1 & 5.

Compatibility is a two way thing, so if I insert the records above, I also defined, that product 5 and product 3 is compatible, with product 1.

The problem comes, when I insert data with product 3 compatible with product 6: id,3,6, an later I need a list, about which products are compatible, with product 1. In this case the list must contains 3,5,6 (because of the connection between 3 and 6).

Because of the huge amount of products and connections, I need a clever way to query this "compatibility chain".

Can someone suggest me a good way? even in clear SQL or in the client side, with C# and LINQ.

Or If someone have a better idea to store the compatibility data, I also open for this solution.

P.s.: sorry for my english

Comment: How long do the chains go? If 1 is compatible with 2, 2 is compatible with 3, and 3 is compatible with 4, then would 2, 3, and 4 be  compatible with 1?

Comment: Use a `CTE`, it's built for recursive relationship like this.

Comment: Jake: yes correct they are all compatible with 1 in this situation.

Comment: AD.NET: it looks promissing, but at this time, I cannot aply the technic for my current problem, but Iam working on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think there is no simple way to do this, but I can figure out a mix of Linq, a recursive method and a foreach Loop that could work.

Supose that you have this 2 classes:

```
        public class Compatible
        {
            public string Prod1_id;
            public string Prod2_id;
        }

        public class Product
        {
            public string Id;
        }
```

And we have a List of compatible products that represents your "Compatible" table. You need to implement a method that gets all the directly compatible products of a single product:

```
    static List<string> GetCompatibles(IEnumerable<Compatible> table,
        string productId, string originalId, List<string> addedProducts)
    {
        return table.Where(c =>
                (c.Prod1_id == productId &&
                c.Prod2_id != originalId &&
                !addedProducts.Contains(c.Prod2_id))
            ).Select(c => c.Prod2_id).ToList();
    }
```

And then, a recursive method which call GetCompatibles with every compatible "child" product found:

```
    static List<string> GetAllCompatibles(List<Compatible> table,
        Product product, Product originalProduct, List<string> addedProducts)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        //Gets all the directly compatible products
        var Childs = GetCompatibles(table, product.Id, originalProduct.Id, addedProducts);

        //Gets all the directly compatible products by retrocompatibility
        Childs.AddRange(GetCompatibles(table.Select(t =>
                        new Compatible { Prod1_id = t.Prod2_id, Prod2_id = t.Prod1_id }
                    ).ToList(), product.Id, originalProduct.Id, addedProducts));
        result.AddRange(Childs);
        addedProducts.AddRange(Childs);
        //Iterates over the directly compatible products
        foreach (string child in Childs)
        {
            //Again, get all the directly compatible products of the "child"
            var temp = GetAllCompatibles(table, new Product { Id = child }, 
                                         originalProduct, addedProducts);
            result.AddRange(temp);

            //If there are childs compatible products, adds it to the final result
            if (temp.Count > 0)
            {
                result.AddRange(temp.Select(p =>
                        GetCompatibles(table, p, originalProduct.Id, addedProducts)
                    ).Aggregate((l1, l2) =>
                        { l1.AddRange(l2); return l1; })
                    );
            }
        }
        return result.Distinct().ToList();
    }
```

Not simple, not elegant, but hey... it works!

Do the main call like this:

```
        Product product = new Product { Id = "1" };

        //List to avoid stack overflow exceptions
        List<string> addedProducts = new List<string>();

        //Gets all the compatible products 1 -> X and X-> 1
        List<string> compatibility = GetAllCompatibles(table, product, product, addedProducts);
```

Comment: This is a nice start but has a problem.  First (as I understand the OP) the compatibility goes both ways (ie. a record that says 1 -> 5 also means 5 -> 1).  Second (and this was the problem I was having trying for a CTE based solution) was the problems with infinite recursion due to cycles (ie. you have 1 -> 5, 5 -> 3 and you need to prevent it from going 1 -> 5 -> 3 -> 5 -> 3 -> ...).  What you have is kinda what I had in mind, I just didn't have time to flesh it out.

Comment: Actually, I've tested it adding a cycle and it worked perfect.

Comment: Daniel Marín: hey it seems working, at first try :) and I think I see it's working mechanism. Thank's for this. I need to test it a bit more.

Comment: unfortunately is not fully working, it seems its not fully two way, the result set contains the only the part of the chain, witch get by the way of prod1_id

when I try to make it work for the prod2_id line, I got overflow, becouse of infinite loop

Comment: now I try to change the way, I store the information, and try to store both way connection, on the first insert, to got the connaction chain reduce only the prod1_id line...

Comment: It's strange, but I got exceptino, on the retro-compatibility part to teh expression:
table.Select(t => 
                        new Compatible { Prod1_id = t.Prod2_id, Prod2_id = t.Prod1_id }
                    ).ToList(),

Explicit construction of entity type '{0}' in query is not allowed.

Comment: If you are working with Entity Framework: you can't create entities as part of a query. Try to create a class that inherits from the entity and use that class in the query.

Comment: Ok, I hack around it, with an internal class, but the result list still not the full chain. 

When I add 2 compatible product for a product, then each of them see the connection until the original product, but not each-other.

example:

product table:

id,name,price
1,A,10
2,B,20
3,C,15


Compatible table:
id,prod1_id,prod2_id
1,1,2
2,1,3

in this case the result I need to see:
for 1 product id: 2,3 (straight connection)
for 2 product id: 1,3 (because of 1=2)
for 3 product id: 1,2 (because of 2=1)

Comment: oh, this anoying formatt less commentbox...
http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=j8DuRCdV

Comment: Wow, that requires a different approach, I've edited the answer.

Comment: for the new version: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2nfYZM

it seems very promissing :)

Comment: The last solution is almost perfect, just one more thing...
For the later handling of compatibilities, I need to get back not only the compatible product ids, but the ID of the record in the compatibilities table, witch describes the "connection".
This information is need for example, when I need to delete a compatibiliy record.

Comment: Yeah, are you gonna pay me? Because I feel like I'm doing all your job.

Comment: I pay yout with accepting the answer, becouse it works as I request in the first question. But I give it a try :D Anyway, thank you for your help!

Comment: Yo, I'm glad you make it. Seems like both of us are learn something. Enjoy!